# They must have dialogue each day, or, they must dialogue each day?

Tags: dialogue

Which is correct? They must have dialogue each day, or, they should dialogue each day?

Comment: Hi @Tasha, Welcome to WritingSE. This question actually belongs on EnglishSE. https://ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: @wetcircuit This question was closed on ELU.SE for lack of research. Based on your comment above was it intended to be migrated there? Or maybe it was intended to be migrated to ELL.SE?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest, clearest form is often the best and most readily understood: "They must speak each day" is what I'd answer.